# How to prevent string from deleting previous parameters in URL?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url

I'm trying to build a service to test remote API's.

The code below adds multiple parameters to a string containing an URL, however when a third parameter is added, it deletes the previous one entered

This is an example what a good URL looks like

```html
http://localhost:5000/api/v1/users?username=kirasiris&page=1
```

Then as soon as I try to enter a third parameter, for example:

```html
http://localhost:5000/api/v1/users?username=kirasiris&page=1&limit=10
```

The result looks like this:

```html
http://localhost:5000/api/v1/users&limit=10
```

```js
let prevValue = ''

newParams.forEach((param, i) => {
  if (param.key.trim() !== '' && param.value.trim() !== '') {
    const encodedKey = encodeURIComponent(param.key)
    const encodedValue = encodeURIComponent(param.value)

    if (newApiURL.match(new RegExp(`[?&]${param.key}=[^&]*`))) {
      newApiURL = newApiURL.replace(new RegExp(`[?&]${param.key}=[^&]*`), '')
    }

    if (param.value.trim() !== '' && param.value !== prevValue) {
      if (i === 0 && !newApiURL.includes('?')) {
        newApiURL += `?${encodedKey}=${encodedValue}`
      } else {
        newApiURL += `${
          newApiURL.startsWith('?') ? '&' : '&'
        }${encodedKey}=${encodedValue}`
      }
      prevValue = param.value
    }
  }
})
```

Is there any way to fix this? I've been trying everything I can think of.

I have a video showcasing the error I'm talking about using the previous block of code:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rCuD9VvE29g

I have also a video showcasing the error thrown when using the code suggested by @NeERAJ TK :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ltcnnR1RDSs